# How do I create an if-else based on datetime hour argument

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement

I need help writing a function depending on if a hour argument is passed to a datetime object or not.

Example with hour argument:
`start_date_dt = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0)`
Example without:
`start_date_dt = datetime(2020, 1, 1)`

Based on if the user passes one of the other I have an if else which generates. I tried the following as a test

```
if start_date_dt.minute is not None:
    print(start_date_dt)

else:
    print(False)
```

but I don't think it is right, because once the object is generated the 00:00:00 portion of the datetime is automatically created and is technically never not none.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to know this information?

Comment: you can split hour minute and second, and then can check these to equal 00:00:00, if this case then you can assume it as without  hour arg, else with hour args.

Comment: One possible solution might be to create your own subclass of `datetime.datetime` that does literally nothing other than check if an hour was passed to its `__init__()` and set an instance variable if so, then call `super().__init__()` after. But this would require people using your code to explicitly opt-in to the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible *out-of-the-box* given that - if not passed - `hour`, `minute` and `second` are defaulted to 0:

```
d1 = datetime(2022, 12, 15)
d2 = datetime(2022, 12, 15, 0, 0, 0)

d1.hour == d2.hour     # True
d1.minute == d2.minute # True
d1.second == d2.second # True
```

You could write a wrapper class:

```
from datetime import datetime

class my_datetime:

    def __init__(self, year, month, day, hour = None, minute = None, second = None):
         hour, self.hour_passed = 0, False if hour is None else hour,True
         minute, self.minute_passed = 0, False if minute is None else minute,True
         second, self.second_passed = 0, False if second is None else second, True
         self.dt = datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your upstream simply passes you the datetime object start_date_dt (with no other information), HH:MM:SS already resolved to 00:00:00, and I think it is almost impossible to determine if the upstream inputted hour=0 or left the hour argument "empty".

Logically it would require you to go one step backward that could make your upstream provide a bit more information to you, by means of a wrapper or a sub-class or whatever.